# System.InvalidOperationException Empty Queue on SendKeys

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook, keyboard-hook

I want to make keyboard hook to replace some keys with another, for example if the use press "ש" then the windows apps get "א" and so on, the idea works fine, but when I set condition to make this replacement when the current language is "Hebrew", My application throws `System.InvalidOperationException` `Empty Queue` on this line `SendKeys.SendWait(char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)res));`, here is my hook method

```
 private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
       if (getCurrentKeyboardLangauge().Contains("he"))
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

                if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 1; }
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 1; }
                if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 1; }
                Console.WriteLine(vkCode + "_" + shift);
                int res = replaceKey.getReplacedKey(vkCode, shift);
                if (res != -1 && ctrl==0 & alt==0)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait(char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)res));
                    return (System.IntPtr)1;
                }else if(vkCode == 79 || vkCode == 89 ||  vkCode == 69 ||  vkCode == 81 ||  vkCode == 220 ||  vkCode == 77 ||  vkCode == 78 ||  vkCode == 66 ||  vkCode == 76 ||  vkCode == 88 ||  vkCode == 90 ||  vkCode == 226){
                    return (System.IntPtr)1;
                }
            }
            else if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Console.WriteLine(vkCode);
                if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 0; }
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 0; }
                if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 0; }                
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static string getCurrentKeyboardLangauge()
    {
        return InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name;
    }
```

Now, What is the wrong in this code? please help